# Validación Formularios Servlet JSP con JQUERY

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

estoy intentando realizar una validación de un campo, en el que si dicho valor del campo ingresado por el usuario ya existe en BD, se envié un mensaje de notificación al usuario de manera inmediata, para ello tengo en mi vista .jsp:

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >FMA:</label>
     <div class="col-sm-4"> 
        <input required type="text" id="txtFMA" name="txtFMA" pattern="[0-9]{9}" maxlength="9" minlength="9"class="form-control"
        placeholder="FMA" 
       value="">
  </div>
  <section id="DatoFMA">
 </section>
</div>
```

Con una función javascript:

```
function validar(){
       $('#txtFMA').keyup(function(){
    var _this = $('#txtFMA');
    var _user = $('#txtFMA').val();
                  if(_user.length == 9){
                         var res = $.ajax({
                             url: 'traslado',
                             dataType: 'json',
                             data: { miPostVar: _user },
                             type: 'post'
                         }).responseText;
                         document.getElementById("DatoFMA").innnerHTML = res;
                     }     
    });

        }
            setInterval(validar,1000);
```

y este es el codigo del servlet:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) 
    {
        FeedlotTraslado td = new FeedlotTraslado();
        this.vfma = request.getParameter("miPostVar");
        try
        {
            if(!td.ExisteFMA(Integer.parseInt(this.vfma))){

                response(response, "error");
            }
        }catch (Exception ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(trasladoDestete.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
}

 private void response(HttpServletResponse resp, String msg)
        throws IOException {
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
       out.println("<h1>" + msg + "</h1>");     
}
  @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
  }
```

Puedo Observar que todo el flujo se ejecuta pero no muestra el mensaje de que error que confirme al usuario que efectivamente ya existe el valor que ingreso. ¿Alguna Solución? o ¿Alguna Forma de Hacer esta validación en tiempo real? Muchas Gracias

Comment: quizá se deba a que te falte la ruta en ajax: url: 'traslado.php',

Comment: si, ya revise, pero estoy desarrollando es en java y al hacer debug entro al servlet de traslado sin problema, el out.println de la funcion response no se muestra en la vista. Gracias